# BeautifulSoup4 Find Method

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I tried scraping some a number from yahoo finance using python3, but all I get is a "None".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SWCH? 
p=SWCH&.tsrc=fin-srch').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

price = soup.find('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)')

print(price)
```

Thanks,
       R.Vij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you pass a list to the `class_` kwarg bs4 will select elements that have ANY of the specified classNames in the document, not ALL of them.

Also you need to note that some of the class values are set dynamically using browser javascript so that they won't appear on the actual document.

I revised your find statement to the following one:

```
soup.find('span', class_=lambda x:x and set(x.split()).issuperset(set("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Fw(b) D(b) Mb(-4px)".split())))
```

The following code returns the current price of `SWCH`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SWCH?p=SWCH&.tsrc=fin-srch').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
price = soup.find('span', class_=lambda x:x and set(x.split()).issuperset(set("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Fw(b) D(b) Mb(-4px)".split())))
print(price.text) # 9.29 for now
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Do you know how the lambda stuff works and what it does? I like to know what code does.

Comment: Beautifulsoup4 would call the lambda function for every element with the value of the class attribute of that element(None if the class attribute does not exist) and select the element if the lambda function returns True. The lambda function checks if the class attribute exists(the first `x and` stuff) and then checks if the actual class names are a superset of the required class names.

Answer (score 0):

`'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'` is not a class but five classes. If you want to find any of them, you should pass them as a list:

```
soup.find('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'.split())  
#<span class="D(ib) W($privatePromoMsgWidth) Fz(12px) Fw(500) Va(m) Wob(n)"...
```

Comment: I tried, but what I got inside the tags was "Now you can search stock related news and private companies such as Airbnb." The result should be "9.29".